# Find PO BOX within address/string

Tags: javascript, regex

I recently made this regex to validate AFO, DPO, FPO and regular PO Box addresses:

`/(^[afd].*?|^)(((p[\s\.]?[o\s][\.]?)\s?)|(post\s?office\s?))((box|bin|b\.?)?\s?(num|number|#)?\s?\d+)/`

It was working perfectly until a user inserted "13605 NE 245th Lane OR PO box 55" as the street address. USPS considers this a valid address but unfortunately this fails my Regex. I cant figure out how to alter the regex to catch the PO Box within the address when a user lists their regular street address first and the PO Box part second. It does catch it when its the other way around.

Any ideas how to alter the regex to account for this new situation but also maintain its current functionality? I'm open to other suggestions or maybe even using two different regexs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`/([afd]?)(((p[\s\.]?[o\s][\.]?)\s?)|(post\s?office\s?))((box|bin|b\.?)?\s?(num|number|#)?\s?\d+)/i`

remove `^` as `PO box 55` is not at the beginning of the address line

Example:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6qsKEo/1)

Comment: Works great so far! Thanks